# Use onchange() to display result based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#locationSelect").change(function () {
          $("#displayText").html($(this).val());
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action='VERIFY.php' method='post'>
<table border = '0'>
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="60" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td><select id='locationSelect' name='location' size='1'>
<option value="csc105">Brock University</option>
<option value="hbhh202">Carleton University</option>
<option value="as990">Centennial</option>
</select></td>
    <td><div id="displayText"></div></td>
 </tr>    
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Post Ad"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

When the client selects a school, i want the value(class code) to display without the browser refreshing. I've tried using document.write() but that would display the value on a blank page and console.log() is not displaying anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from your variable name. You are logging the value as a string literal.
console.log(classCode);

Comment: Why do you pass `myForm` as an argument, then hard-code the form number in the function instead of using the argument?

Comment: document.write("<p>"+classCode+"</p>"). This should work

Comment: There's no PHP here.

Comment: @MDJ Please don't suggest `document.write()`.

Comment: Well, My point was to just make a note of the quotes placed in the code.Will make sure that I do not suggest document.write henceforth. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery, it may be easier if you changed a few things:

- Remove the onClick method from your select element
- Give your select element a unique id
- Use the Jquery syntax to get elements by id `$("#elementId")`
- Add a `div` or `span` to show your result

The following is a working example:

### **HTML**

```
<form action='VERIFY.php' method='post'>
  <select name='location' id="locationSelect" size='1'>
    <option value="csc105">Brock University</option>
    <option value="hbhh202">Carleton University</option>
    <option value="as990">Centennial</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<div id="displayText">
</div>
```

### **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#locationSelect").change(function () {
        $("#displayText").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

### **Working Example**

You can see a [working example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/8wxuya7x/).

### **Explanation**

- `$(document).ready()` - The document is ready for manipulation
- `$("#locationSelect").change` - Handles the change event on an element with an id of `locationSelect`.
- `$("#displayText").html` - Gets or sets the html for an element with an id of displayText
- `$(this).val()` - The value of whatever element we are currently working on (in this case, the `option` that was selected)

### **Resources**

- [JQuery Document Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [JQuery Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [Jquery Html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [Jquery Val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

### **Follow-Up:**

You need an open and closing `<script>` tag to contain your Jquery, *separate from where you load the library*:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- The above line needs to be separate from the script tag that contains your JQuery -->
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#locationSelect").change(function () {
          $("#displayText").html($(this).val());
       });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made the changes you suggested but it still does not work. My code was really large and I did not add the whole thing. However, I have edited to include more.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for listing the resources!

Answer (score 0):

Display the result in a `DIV` or `SPAN` in the document:

```
<form action='VERIFY.php' method='post'>
    <select name='location' size='1' onchange="handleSelect(this.form)">
        <option value="csc105">Brock University</option>
        <option value="hbhh202">Carleton University</option>
        <option value="as990">Centennial</option>
    </select>
</form>
<p>You chose: <span id="output"></span></p>

<script>
function handleSelect(myForm)
{ 
    var classCode = myForm.location.value;
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = classCode;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` will only log the result to your development console in FireFox or Chrome. This is great for checking your resulting data, but if you want the data to show up on the page then you have to give it a jQuery selector identifying an element to put the data in like the below:

**EXAMPLE**

```
<form action='VERIFY.php' method='post'>
    <select id="location" name='location' size='1'>
        <option value="csc105">Brock University</option>
        <option value="hbhh202">Carleton University</option>
        <option value="as990">Centennial</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="result"><div>

<script>
$('#location').on('change', function () {
    var classCode = document.forms[0].location.value;
    $('#result').html('<p>' + classCode + '</p>');
});
</script>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ggpm101/)**

As you can see the resulting data (classCode) is placed in the `result` div. [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) allows you to fill the div with `html` but there is many ways to add content to a div. In this instance that is probably best, but I would recommend learning a few such as: [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), and [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

**Note:** The example used `event handlers` that are outside the HTML content. This is not required, it is just how I organize my jQuery code to help it be more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made the changes you suggested but it still does not work. My code was really large and I did not add the whole thing. However, I have edited to include more.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update your javascript code like:

```
function handleSelect(myForm)
{ 
    var classCode = myForm.location.value;
    console.log("<p>" + classCode + "</p>");
}
```